# .NET XML web-service and NHibernate: how work with properties

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, nhibernate

My domain library for database created with nhibernate. When I was create web-service under with library I was catch many errors about can't using interfaces in my DataContract classes. e.q.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    ... 
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<Item> Items {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

next, I was decide add some ploy: I was add other property with type List:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    ...
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual IList<Item> prItems {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<Item> Items {
        get{
            return this.prItems.ToList(); 
       }
       set{
           this.prItems = value;
       }
    }
    ...
}
```

this work fine - I can get list on my client, but when I need change list of items - this is empty on server, because client nothing know about prItems. 
What you can advice for me?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use class instances that are loaded using NHibernate and contains collections since NHibernate use proxy collection classes for lazy loading and the NHibernate collection proxy classes are not serializable.

Build separate DTO classes that you use in your web service interface.

Comment: The implementation (the transparent proxy) is not serialized, the interface (`IList<Item>`) is. So it should work anyway, right?

Comment: @jgauffin: no, it is the concrete implementation (the transparent proxy as you say) that is serialized. And since it is not serializable in NHibernate, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use your initial attempt, but with an additional attribute:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(List<Item>))]
public class MyClass
{
    ... 
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<Item> Items {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

**Edit:**

Updated KnownType to a complete generic definition

Comment: Are you sure? When I try use this, again I get error - interface can't be serialize how and earlier.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure (at least for non-nhibernate projects, but they should work the same, even if transparent proxies are used). I just tested it. The problem was that it was a generic definition but KnownType only declared `typeof(List)`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: From MSDN: "The KnownTypeAttribute class allows you to specify, in advance, the types that should be included for consideration during deserialization." Note that this only specifies behavior during deserialization. The problem here is that serialization does not work, so adding the KnownType attribute will not work.